# How to get my JQuery Accordion to work?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

**Links**

- [**JQuery Accordion on JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tovic/CzE3q/)
- [**My JSFiddle Accordion Attempt**](http://jsfiddle.net/CzE3q/450/)

I have found a basic, JQuery Accordion on JSFiddle, of which you can see in the 'Links' section of this question. You can also see how I am trying to implement the JQuery Accordion into my website in the 'Links' section too.

The 'JQuery Accordion on JSFiddle' link is the original I have come across via a Google Search.     $(function() {

```
$(function() {
    $('#accordion .content').hide();
    $('#accordion h2:first').addClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
    $('#accordion h2').click(function() {
        if($(this).next().is(':hidden')) {
            $('#accordion h2').removeClass('active').next().slideUp('slow');
            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Whereas on my version, the content in the JQuery Accordion is hidden on load, however the buttons do not show my content in the modified version.

Thank you very much for any help and/or advice in resolving my problems.

Best Regards,
Tim

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? You can download [jQuery UI's accordion widget](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) and just plug your content in. You'll probably have to spend some time styling it just how you want it, but the functionality is tested and proven already. You can build a custom download of jQuery UI that just includes the accordion widget (or any other widgets you choose) so that your users don't download tons of other unnecessary widget code.

Comment: The link you have attached appears to have the same source code for the orignal I have posted, therefore I will still encounter problems trying to implement it into my page as this is not the first time I have tried. I have come here for a last resort really, so to speak. Thanks for your feedback ajp15243.

Comment: I don't see how the source code you posted is the same as theirs... you're trying to use plain jQuery and manually add the functionality of the accordion. The jQuery UI link has source code that just has markup laid out, and all they do is link the jQuery & jQuery UI libraries in their `<head>` tag, and then throw in this JavaScript: `$(function() { $( "#accordion" ).accordion(); });`. That's it. You have an accordion with that. You don't have to manually toggle classes and make calls to `.slideUp()` or `.slideDown()` like you're doing. That's all done in the jQuery UI library for you.

Comment: I am regarding the 'Original' version I attached a link to @ajp15243 as they use header tags for the buttons to collapse the hidden contents as does the example. I'll play around as it is done differently but still uses the same rules.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure how I can work with the source code on the link you have provided as it doesn't how how to specify where the buttons are so and whatnot but that you for your input.